# Using certificate with an IdentityServer4 protected API

Tags: certificate, identityserver4, x509certificate

I'm trying to improve security of a service based on IdentityServer 4.
This service is being used to protect an API.
I successfully configured it to use a X509 certificate and all seems to be working as expected.
The thing is that I couldn't find any more information on this particular scenario (protected API and respective clients).
Do I need to change anything on the API and clients?

Comment: I think you need to elaborate on what your actual problem is to get the best help possible here. Try structuring your question something like: 1) what you are trying to achieve 2) what you've tried 3) your problems/issues/questions/challenges

Comment: 1) I'm trying to improve the security of a an API protected by a service based on IdentityServer 4.
2) I Successfully configured it to use a X509 certificate and is working as expected.
3) Due to the lack of information on the subject I don't know if this is enough and I'm seeking the advice of someone with more knowledge on the subject.

Comment: IdentityServer is an implementation of certain [specifications](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/intro/specs.html). But there exist many (other) specifications that are not implemented (yet). I'm sure you'll find answers there. One thing you can do is check the expiration of the certificate. If I'm not mistaken IdentityServer is ignoring the expiration date.

Comment: Will do, thank you.